# Rails hosting for small app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, hosting

I have small rails application with mysql2 database (2 tables), backbone and bootstrap. I think, that that amount of visits will be max 50ppl per week, so I want to find cheap (~10 $/m or cheаper) hosting for it. I found dreamhost, is it good or not? What else you can suggest to me?

Comment: Heroku is an excellent service, and worth taking a look at while this question is closed by a moderator.

Comment: @JavaNut13 I was thinking about heroku, but is there any limits for free app?

Comment: Apart from a limit to database rows (~10000) and slow load (you app needs to be loaded when someone requests it, but performs fine once the homepage has loaded) For an idea this is my free-hosted Heroku app: http://snippetshare.heroku.com

Comment: @JavaNut13 I know about slow load, so I use backbone for faster navigation in my site

Comment: Well then I'd put it on Heroku. You can always db:pull the database and put it on another server if it doesn't meet your needs.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I usually run all my small rails apps off **heroku.com** if your app is under 100meg(images you put on amazon s3 wich is also free if you use the free tier). Heroku has very easy deployment aswell :D Hope this helps.

---

here is a how to for heroku
https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/rails3

---

here is how to for amazon s3 (to store your images or whatever you like to store there)
http://doganberktas.com/2010/09/14/amazon-s3-and-paperclip-rails-3/

---

Alternatives to heroku

- EngineYard - http://www.engineyard.com/products/cloud
- Openshift - https://openshift.redhat.com/app/
- Amazon - [Tutorial On Deploying Rails Apps to the Amazon Cloud?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1401155/tutorial-on-deploying-rails-apps-to-the-amazon-cloud)

Comment: I don't want Heroku, cause my ping to their servers is 200. And, i can't find anything about limits.

Comment: looks S3 is not free. It is cheapest option though

Answer (score 1):

http://www.heroku.com/ - 0$/m for small projects.
I have two projects on heroku for more then one year. Not one of them has not yet become a hightloaded. And I paid 0$ for all time.

Answer (score 1):

I've used Linode (linode.com) for many years with hardly any problems. Their cheapest plans do start at $19.9 though.

Comment: seconding linode.  Heroku is a good starting point but once you start needing workers or additional dynos.  It gets expensive pretty fast.

Comment: Linode ftw! And that's all I have to say about that...

Answer (score 0):

Check out [Heroku](http://heroku.com) and [Amazon Web Services](http://aws.amazon.com/).